# Two way binding to PasswordBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm-light

My PasswordBox is bound to the ViewModel like:

```
 xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
.
.
.
<PasswordBox x:Name="pwbox" >
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
         <i:EventTrigger EventName="PasswordChanged" >
               <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PasswordChangedCommand }"  CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=pwbox,  Mode=OneWay}"/>
         </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
 </PasswordBox>
```

And in the view model:

```
public ICommand PasswordChangedCommand { get; private set; }
private string password;
public MyVMClass()
{
  PasswordChangedCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(PasswordChangedMethod);
}
private void PasswordChangedMethod(object obj)
{           
    password = ((System.Windows.Controls.PasswordBox)obj).Password;
}
```

It works fine in one way, i.e If I enter the password inside view, I can access it from the viewmodel,
my question: how can I bound the password to the other way, i.e if I change it via ViewModel I want to see the change in the view.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong way. `PasswordBox` component is an exception.

If you going to make it two-way bind-able you broke security concept, because it's mean that somewhere in RAM password will be stored as PLAIN text, in your case in variable

```
private string password
```

Until last moment (real username/password validation), always try to pass password as `((PasswordBox)o).SecurePassword`. Yes, it's broke `MVVM` pattern, but this is cost of security.

Comment: I'm not keeping it as plain text, i have some encryption algorithm, does anybody knows the answer please?

Comment: change `Mode=OneWay` to `Mode=TwoWay` ?

Comment: If so `Path` also should be added, I need code snippet please